# Why is $0 different between `sh myscript` and `source myscript`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a very simple shell scripts name `test.sh`:

```
[mylinux ~]$ cat test.sh
echo "a"
echo "${0}"
```

However, when I `source` it and `sh` it, the results are quite different:

```
[mylinux ~]$ sh test.sh 
a
test.sh
[mylinux ~]$ source test.sh 
array : x, y
0,x
1,x
```

I can't understand the results of `source test.sh`, and, after I changed the name of `test.sh`, the results changed also:

```
[mylinux ~]$ mv test.sh a.sh
[mylinux ~]$ source a.sh 
a
-bash
```

How can I understand this phenomenon?

### BTW, the second strange results only exits in one of my remote linux session, in my local linux system, everything works fine. So for sure it's related to the environment, and what I can do to find the fundamental reason?

I found the real problem, that is, even if their is no such a file `test.sh`, I can even perform `source test.sh` to get the results:

```
[mylinux ~]$ rm test.sh 
[mylinux ~]$ source test.sh
array : x, y
0,x
1,x
```

This is quite strange for me...

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Generally, "$0" is the name of the program or script you are running.  What systems are you on?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I just couldn't understand the results of  `source test.sh`, it's seems weird for me, and I edited the question a bit now.

Comment: [have a look at this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/618442) thats why first you got the filename from ${0} and last example you got bash, because its executed from there

Comment: @Jack It's Scientific Linux 6

Comment: Your purported output is incorrect.

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, but the second result,  `array :x, y bla bla` cannot be explained yet...

Comment: @springcc can you recreate this? i done everything you mentioned here and cannot recreate it.

Comment: @chepner Are you mean the second result? It is strange but it's exactly what I got from my side, no typo...

Comment: @Sebastian This phenomenon are only exits in one of my remote linux session, I don't the problem in my local linux, so for sure it's related to the environment of the shell, do you know how to investigate it?

Comment: Closely related: [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028). BTW, tagging the question `bash` and executing commands with `sh` is internally inconsistent -- `sh` only guarantees a POSIX sh interpreter; even if that interpreter is bash, it'll run in compatibility mode. Use `bash yourscript`, not `sh yourscript`, to run a script with bash.

Comment: BTW, the word "bug" (as given in the original title) only applies if there's a documented guarantee being violated. Citing documentation is usually a good thing if trying to support such a claim.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes you I agree, I modified then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` performs path lookup on its argument if the argument doesn't contain any `/` characters, so while `sh test.sh` and `source ./test.sh` are guaranteed to be running code from a file in the current directory, `source test.sh` may be running a different script entirely. `source test.sh` will only run `./test.sh` if it doesn't find `test.sh` in your `PATH` first.

Comment: Exactly, I get the results I expected when I using the `source ./test.sh`, BTW, how can I get the specific path for the test.sh I actually executed? I mean, is there some convenient method to find the path rather than look into the path in $PATH one by one?

Comment: Try `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` (see the man page for more information on this array. It should contain the absolute path of the executed script if it is found via path lookup; otherwise, it will still be whatever argument you passed to `source`.

Comment: `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` is just blank actually

Comment: Sorry, that would be how you find out inside the script. Outside, use `type test.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `source test.sh`, a new shell is not created, so the program, `${0}`, is bash.  When you run `sh test.sh`, bash creates a new shell, and sets `${0}` to the name of the script.

Comment: Just ran it in RHEL6 (which is what Scientific Linux is based on), and get "bash".  What happens when you run `echo $0` from the command line?

Comment: Just `-bash`, and  the second strange results only exits in one of my remote linux session, in my local linux system, everything works fine.